# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is not working as expected

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute a command with the method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` but it is not working. In the terminal it works just fine,

The command in question is the following:

`gcc ~/library/build/*.o -o ~/library/build/application -L ~/library/build -lpstr`

My Test Code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String cmd =
                    "gcc ~/library/build/*.o " +
                            "-o ~/library/build/application " +
                            "-L ~/library/build -lpstr";
            System.out.println(String.format("Command: \"%s\"", cmd));
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            BufferedReader std = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            p.waitFor();

            String message;

            System.out.println("Standard output:");
            while ((message = std.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(message);

            System.out.println("Error output:");
            while ((message = err.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(message);

            System.exit(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Test code output:

```
Command: "gcc ~/library/build/*.o -o ~/library/build/application -L ~/library/build -lpstr"
Standard output:
Error output:
gcc: error: ~/library/build/*.o: No such file or directory
```

---

Terminal test:

> ```
> michael@MICHAEL-PC:~/library$ tree
> .
> ├── build
> │   ├── libpstr.a
> │   ├── main.o
> │   └── util.o
> ├── main.c
> ├── util.c
> └── util.h
>
> 1 directory, 6 files
> michael@MICHAEL-PC:~/library$ gcc ~/library/build/*.o -o ~/library/build/application -L ~/library/build -lpstr
> michael@MICHAEL-PC:~/library$ tree
> .
> ├── build
> │   ├── application
> │   ├── libpstr.a
> │   ├── main.o
> │   └── util.o
> ├── main.c
> ├── util.c
> └── util.h
>
> 1 directory, 7 files
> michael@MICHAEL-PC:~/library$
> ```

Comment: The '~' and the * are interpreted by a shell.  Here you are not using a shell, instead you're invoking 'gcc' directly. You will need to expand the '~' and the '*' yourself

Comment: @Bruno Caceiro Please do not translate questions to English: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: @Codeer I understand. But, tbh, if the code was in english, the OP should be able to understand. Next time I won't translate, thanks for the advise.

Comment: @DavidZimmerman there is another way to do it? Some bash command parser or something else?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco run the command with a shell, cmd = "bash -c \"gcc ...